# Attribution of variables to matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In the case of a system of linear equations say -
$$x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 = 1 $$
$$5x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 4 $$
$$x_1 + x_2 + 7x_3 = 2$$

we denote this with a matrix as -

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 
5 & 1 & 1 & 4\\ 
1 & 1 & 7 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

where the variables change row-wise and down the coloumns the variables are the same (what I mean is the variables corresponding to those coefficients are in this order)

Is it always like this or is it arbitrary ?

For example while representing basis vectors for R3, (assume the below matrix contains arbitrary basis vectors for R3)

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}

How will you interpret these vectors ? coloumn-wise or row-wise and is there a convention ?

Comment: sorry, my question was a duplicate of : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862278/combining-column-and-row-wise-meanings-of-a-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write your system as$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 \\
5 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 7
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
4\\
2
\end{pmatrix}$$
and that is how you get the matrix that you were talking about. This yields that the first column corresponds to the coefficients of $x_1$ etc.

Comment: What about in the case of vectors ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you see a 3x3 matrix and somebody tell's you there are 3 vectors in it, do you interpret row-wise or coloumn-wise

Comment: Well, there are reasons to look at both and one should better specify that, but I would assume that he was talking about the columns.